# set gcp service key json file at runtime for rest api

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, postman

I want to set my google json credential file at run time through postman. I have made a bigquery rest api. Right now I am passing it in my code like this:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'C:/Users/Documents/bigQuery/service.json'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_request():
    query:
.
.
.
     return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I tried taking the input from form data in postman approach but the code throws compile time error asking for credential file to be set up first.

**compilation error:**

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials.
Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is needed for the code to fetch the big query data.
I want postman for passing the key.json file to the code at run time.

Comment: 1) Your code in your question does not use/require a service account. 2) Setting an environment variable in your Python code only affects your Python code or its child processes. 3) You mention s compile time error. What is the error? 4) What does Postman have to do with your question? Edit your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley hope I have answered all your queries.
Hope you have some answers.

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but you can also pass the JSON file directly when creating the BQ client. See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code). Note that it is for GCStorage but it should work for BQ as well, as the auth for the client libraries is the same.

Comment: @EdoAkse in your suggestion too we have to set the key in the code itself, which is not my requirement. I want to pass the key file at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the env variable, there are 2 other options:

1. Create the client using `client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(json_credentials_path)` as per [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.from_service_account_json).
2. Create the client using `client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_info(json_object)` as per [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.from_service_account_info).

Either way will allow you to pass the credentials at runtime. See the example below for the second option. The first option should be quite evident.

As you can see in the code below, the credentials get set on the client side, not on the server side.

**server.py**

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from flask import Flask, request
import json


app = Flask(__name__)


def querysomething(json_object):
    # https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.from_service_account_info
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_info(json_object)
    # example below stolen from:
    # https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library
    query = """
        SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
        WHERE state = 'TX'
        GROUP BY name, state
        ORDER BY total_people DESC
        LIMIT 20
    """
    query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.
    print("The query data:")
    for row in query_job:
        # Row values can be accessed by field name or index.
        print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0], row["total_people"]))


@app.route("/api/query", methods=["POST"])
def api_query():
    print(request.is_json)
    json_object = json.loads(request.get_json())
    print(json_object)
    querysomething(json_object)
    return "ok"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**client.py**

```py
import requests
import json


with open("credentials.json") as infile:
    credentials = json.load(infile)


target = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/query"
asjson = json.dumps(credentials)
response = requests.post(target, json=asjson)
print(response, response.text)
```